# Is it possible to have a grid inside a cell with 960?

Tags: css, 960.gs

I like 960 as an easy way of doing the layout of web sites. However, I'm not sure of it's capabilities.

I want to have a grid with 2 columns (grid_4) and 2 rows on the main part of my page and a column on the right (grid_4).

Is it possible to define a first grid of 8 colums and a second of 4 columns and then to put other cells inside the first column?

The pseudo structure:

```
grid_8
    >grid_4
    >grid_4
grid_4
```

The main idea is to have the last column with a different height of the main grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a set of grids inside a grid you use the `.alpha` and `.omega` classes.

```
<div class="grid_8">
    <div class="grid_4 alpha"> ... </div>
    <div class="grid_4 omega"> ... </div>
</div>
```

`.alpha` - removes the margin-left

`.omega` - removes the margin-right

You can also apply this to multiple inner grids.

```
<div class="grid_12">
    <div class="grid_4 alpha"> ... </div>
    <div class="grid_4"> ... </div>
    <div class="grid_4 omega"> ... </div>
</div>
```